# How to use author meta in shortcode?

Tags: functions, shortcode, amazon

I am trying to create a shortcode that will return a link to a book on Amazon with a specific affiliate tracking code specific to the author. I created a user option called "amz" to hold the author's tracking code. This works fine when I'm using it elsewhere. This is the shortcode I created:

`function amazon_link_function($atts, $content = null) {
      extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'isbn' => ' ',
      'title' => ' '
      ), $atts));`

```
  $amztrack = the_author_meta( 'amz' );

  return '<a href="http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/' .$isbn. '/' .$amztrack. '" title="' .$title. '" target="_blank">' .$title. '</a>';
```

}
   add_shortcode("amazon", "amazon_link_function");

The isbn and title values return properly, but the tracking code stored in the $amztrack variable is displayed as plain text *before* the paragraph the shortcode is used in:(

I also tired this for the return line and got the same result:

```
  return '<a href="http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/' .$isbn. '/' .the_author_meta( 'amz' ). '" title="' .$title. '" target="_blank">' .$title. '</a>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_author_meta()` prints the content immediately. Use instead:

```
$amztrack = get_the_author_meta( 'amz', FALSE );
```

This will *return* the value.

Comment: Boom! I havn't even finished editing the question for format and you solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

shortcodes need to *return* the value, therefore you cannot use a function which prints the output, like `the_author_meta()`;

use `get_the_author_meta()`  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta